# Is there a way to send a ping packet using glib/gio/gtk/etc?

Tags: sockets, ping, gio

In my GTK app, I am trying to determine whether a local networked device is online.
Looking at some online examples of how to send a ping packet, they all seem to open a socket using IPPROTO_ICMP.

For example:-

`sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);`

I'm trying to create the same using GIO functions, along the lines of:-

`GSocket* sock_ping = g_socket_new(G_SOCKET_FAMILY_IPV4, G_SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM, G_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_????, NULL);`

But what do I use for the protocol type ?
Gio.SocketProtocol enum does not list any such type.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?
Or, if a "ping" is not possible, maybe suggest another method ?